# Java8 if statement replacement with FP concepts inside try-catch block

Tags: java, functional-programming

could someone please show me a way to replace if statement inside try block with functional programming concepts. No conditional operators, thanks.

```
    Predicate<Integer> isNegativeOrZero = i -> i <= 0;
    try {
        if (isNegativeOrZero.test(n)) throw new java.lang.Error("Negative number");
        return process(n);
    } catch(Error e) {
        return STATE.ERROR;
    }
```

Replacing this line of code:

```
if (isNegativeOrZero.test(n)) throw new java.lang.Error("Negative number");
```

Comment: This really looks like trying to use functional programming "just because". It is far more easily expressed using plain old conditional statements/expressions.

Comment: Does `process` throw `Error`? Are you aware that Error should only be used for uncoverable situations (e.g. out of memory), where basically the only sensible thing to do is to give up and crash the program? Given this, if you are expecting that `process` may fail, it should be throwing a checked exception (a subtype of Exception, but not a subtype of RuntimeException).

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree, this part is poorly done from my side, thanks for given information related to this. But these were requirements given by university in one of tasks. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the following?

```
return i <= 0 ? STATE.ERROR : process(n);
```

In which case you won't get any simpler but you can write

```
return Optional.of(n)
    .filter(i -> i > 0)
    .map(i -> process(i))
    .orElse(STATE.ERROR);
```

In short, you should avoid using Exceptions/Errors where possible esp for control, but in functional programming, you need to remove them or it will be ugly.

Comment: This assumes that `process` doesn't also throw Error (not that you should be catching Error anyway...).

Comment: These are just university requirements for task (get rid of given if statements with functional programming concepts, no ifs, loops etc..), not a fan of doing it this way, but it works and covers requirments. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarisRucko this doesn't meet your requirement of "no conditional operators": `?:` is the conditional operator. Did you mean "no conditional *statements*"?

Comment: The lambda passed to map could be replaced method reference. Could not edit answer since it's not clear if it's an instance or a static method.